# completion of $C_{00}$ with different (semi)norms

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $C_{00}(I)$ be space of complex sequences indexed by countable set $I$ with entries are zero for all but finitely many entries.

We endow $C_{00}(I)$ with the following family of (semi)-norms:

$\lVert b_i \rVert_n = \sum_i(1+L(i))^n|b_i|$ where L is function from $I$ to positive reals. My questions are:

1. Is the completion w.r.t family of seminorms of $C_{00}(I)$ well known space? (of course depends on $L$)
2. Note that the family of seminorms is actually family of norms. Does it remain family of norms in the completion also? (or it may become family of honest seminorms?)

Comment: The completion is a particular *Köthe sequence space of order $1$*. In general, you have an arbitrary matrix $A$ of weights $a_{n,i}$ with $a_{n,i}\le a_{n+1,i}$ and consider $\lambda^1(A)=\lbrace (x_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}: \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty a_{n,i}|x_i|<\infty \text{ for all } n\rbrace$.

Answer (score 0):

1. With one such norm, the space is called a *weighted $\ell^1$ space*. I'm not aware of any term for the space you get using the collection of norms.
2. The norms will remain norms after completion. Indeed, any Cauchy sequence with respect to these norms converges componentwise, which allows us to identify its limit with a sequence indexed by $I$. Clearly, for any sequence that is not identically zero these norms are all positive.